# Combine `STDOUT` and `STDIN` into a single `IO` object

Tags: ruby, unix

Is there a way to create a single `IO` object whose read stream is the current process's `STDOUT` and whose write stream is the current process's `STDIN`?

This is similar to `IO.popen`, which runs a command as a subprocess and returns an `IO` object connected to the subprocesses standard streams. However, I don't want to run a subprocess, I want to use the current Ruby process.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create a single IO object

No. STDIN and STDOUT are two different file descriptors. An IO represents a single FD.

You can however, make something that acts like an IO object.
This probably contains a bunch of bugs as duplicating FDs is often bad.

```
require "forwardable"
class IOTee < IO
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@in, 
    :close_read, 
    :read, 
    :read_nonblock, 
    :readchar, 
    :readlines, 
    :readpartial, 
    :sysread

  def_delegators :@out, 
    :close_write,
    :syswrite, 
    :write, 
    :write_nonblock

  def initialize(input,output)
    @in = input
    @out = output
  end
end

io = IOTee.new(STDIN,STDOUT) # You would swap these
io.puts("hi")
hi
=> nil
```

Depending on what you're doing there is `IO#pipe` and `IO#reopen` which could also be helpful.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-reopen

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe

I suspect that the above isn't really the problem you want to solve, but the problem you hit with your solution to the problem.

I suspect really making a pipe and reopening `STDOUT` and `STDIN` to either end is what you're really after. Combining them in a single IO object doesn't make much sense.

Also, if you were talking to yourself via `STDIN` and `STDOUT`, it would be very easy to reach a deadlock while you wait for yourself to read or write data.

Comment: Yeah I basically ended up reopening each end of a pipe like you suggested. I guess I'm just confused about how `IO.popen` can connect a subprocess' standard streams to a single file descriptor but the same can't be done with the main process.